# How to correctly append dynamic GetUIKit accordions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getuikit

I'm trying to *dynamically* append [UIKit Accordions](http://getuikit.com/docs/accordion.html) into a sortable list. The initial items (accordions) are working, [but the dynamically appended is not working](http://jsfiddle.net/g81zLfc0/1/).

#### HTML

```
<div class="second-list"  data-uk-observe>
    <div class="uk-sortable uk-margin uk-accordion" data-uk-sortable="{group:'test'}" data-uk-accordion="{showfirst: false}">
        <div class="uk-margin">
            <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box uk-accordion-title">Item 1
                <button class="uk-button delete-btn">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="uk-accordion-content">test1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
            <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box uk-accordion-title">Item 2
                <button class="uk-button delete-btn">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="uk-accordion-content">test2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
// Remove item handler
$(".delete-btn").on("click", function () {
    // 400 is default
    $(this).closest(".uk-margin").fadeOut(400, function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
    return false;
});

function addItem () {
    var $container = $(".second-list").find("[data-uk-sortable]");
    $container.append(
    `<div class="uk-margin">
            <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box uk-accordion-title">new item
                <button class="uk-button delete-btn">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="uk-accordion-content">description</div>
        </div>`
    );
}

addItem();
```

This is the minimal example I created to reproduce the problem. The sortable dynamic item is working fine (can be dragged), but the accordion doesn't. When clicking it, I'm getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```

What I have tried:

- Using `data-uk-observe` in the sortable element. I don't feel any difference using it.
- Trying to initialize the accordion using the UIKit API:

  ```
  UIkit.accordion($(".uk-margin"));
  UIkit.accordion($(".uk-accordion-title"));
  UIkit.accordion($(".uk-accordion-content"));
  ```

  None of these doesn't fixe the problem.

So, how to correctly append dynamic GetUIKit accordions?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/g81zLfc0/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you want to do is:

- Omit the `data-uk-accordion` attribute.
- Save the object returned from calling `UIkit.accordion(element, options)`.
- After new accordion child elements have been added, call `accordion.update()`. (assuming you saved the returned object above in a variable called `accordion`)

For more information about how I arrived at that, check out [the related issue on GitHub](https://github.com/uikit/uikit/issues/1659).

(also posted as an answer on [UIKit accordion and ng-repeat doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189220/uikit-accordion-and-ng-repeat-doesnt-work/35946697#35946697))

Comment: Can you provide a demo?

Comment: @IonicăBizău: I've created [a demo on CodePen](http://codepen.io/whitelynx/pen/beBdjL) based on the code you provided in the question. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the accordion data from the element before you reinitialize it:

```
$(".uk-margin").removeData("accordion");
UIkit.accordion($(".uk-margin"));
```

That worked for me when I was writing an angular directive for this.

Comment: Demo? I tried it, but doesn't really work. It's buggy.

Answer (score 0):

try update all items of accordion after add,

```
var component = UIkit.accordion($('.uk-accordion'));
component.update();
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I'm using Meteor. This took me a good hour to get worked out, and I tried several different solutions, including using `Template.onRender`, `Template.onCreated`, but to no avail. They all seemed to attempt to initialize the UIKit accordion JS too soon.

I probably should've known better, but the right answer was to put @codermonkeyfuel's code before the end of my template helper, like so:

```
Template.appsList.helpers({
  myApps: function() {
    if (Meteor.user() ) {
      console.log("we have a user: " + Meteor.user() );
      var userId = Meteor.userId();
      var user = Meteor.users.findOne(Meteor.userId());
      console.log("userId: " + userId);

      var apps = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userId}, {
        fields: {
          myApps: 1
        }
      }).myApps;
      // console.log(myApps);
      return user && apps;
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
      var accordion = UIkit.accordion($('.uk-accordion'), {collapse: false});
      accordion.update();
    }, 1000)
  }
});
```

My head was thinking it was a timing issue with the rendering. In retrospect, the actual solution makes perfect sense. Hope it's useful for anyone using UIKit with MeteorJS.
[meteor](/questions/tagged/meteor) [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [uikit](/questions/tagged/uikit)