# UIKit accordion and ng-repeat doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, getuikit

I'm adding new accordion sections to my UIKit data-uk-accordion dynamically, using ng-repeat.

```
<div class="uk-accordion" data-uk-accordion="{ collapse: false }">
  <h3 class="uk-accordion-title uk-active" ng-repeat-start="driver in drivers">Driver {{driver.id}}</h3>
  <div class="uk-accordion-content" ng-repeat-end>
  ...
</div>
```

When I add new accordion sections and I click on the title to collapse, I'm getting the following error:

TypeError: wrapper is undefined, on line 73 of accordion.js in UIkit 2.24.2:
`wrapper.data('toggle').toggleClass(this.options.clsactive);`

I tried adding `data-uk-observe` to the accordion div, or its parent divs but didn't have any effect, and also tried to reinit the accordion manually by adding it an id, and running UIkit.accordion('#drivers') from console but no change.

Even tried to run `UIkit.init()` from console but I'm getting the same error.

Any ideas how to reinit the accordion?

Comment: You should initialize manually the accordion with UIkit.accordion($('#elementID'), {option: 'value'}); Omit the data-uk-accordion attribute to prevent the component from booting before.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731080/how-to-correctly-append-dynamic-getuikit-accordions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want to do is:

- Omit the `data-uk-accordion` attribute.
- Save the object returned from calling `UIkit.accordion(element, options)`.
- After new accordion child elements have been added, call `accordion.update()`. (assuming you saved the returned object above in a variable called `accordion`)

For more information about how I arrived at that, check out [the related issue on GitHub](https://github.com/uikit/uikit/issues/1659).